# get the nearest nested list from a given nested list

Tags: python, list, nested, nested-lists

So I have a 2 values `[-82.819309,40.081296]` and a list of multiple nested values like

```
[[-83.0347849999999, 39.945993],
 [-82.957851, 40.060118],
 [-82.994303, 40.013227],
 [-82.8265609999999, 39.9207779999999],
 [-82.9984709999999, 39.887616],
 ...]
```

Now I want to get the list from the nested list whose difference from the two values is the minimum.
something like

```
>>> getmin([1,2], [[1,1],[1,4],[2,3],[3,2]]) 
[1,1]
```

Logic:

```
[1,2] - [1,1] = abs(1-1) + abs(2-1) -> 1
[1,2] - [1,4] = abs(1-1) + abs(2-4) -> 2
[1,2] - [2,3] = abs(1-2) + abs(2-3) -> 2
[1,2] - [3,2] = abs(1-3) + abs(2-2) -> 2
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: First you have to define exactly how this difference is calculated to result in a single number. Then you should show your own effort (code) as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Consider using `numpy`.  Multiply your vector by `np.ones` to make a matrix of the same size as the match values.  Subtract them.  Then use `np.norm` to compute the norm of the rows (you can specify what type of norm to use, based on what you want to be considered "closest") and `np.argmin` to find the index of the smallest one.

Comment: I have updated the question with how I want the min to be calculated. @MichaelButscher

Comment: @Tallion 22 I can't find `numpy.norm` anywhere online. I know you can use `numpy.linalg.norm`. To get the specified metric (which is known as the 'cityblock' metric), use the kwarg `ord=1`.

Comment: @Michael Sohnen - thanks for the correcting my typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use very simple code:

```
import numpy as np

mylist = [[-83.0347849999999, 39.945993],
 [-82.957851, 40.060118],
 [-82.994303, 40.013227],
 [-82.8265609999999, 39.9207779999999],
 [-82.9984709999999, 39.887616],
 ...]

def item_of_min_norm(target_coordinate):
    norms  = [np.linalg.norm(np.array(target_coordinate,float)-np.array(item,float), ord=1) for item in mylist]
    index_of_minimum = np.argmin(norms)
    minimum_item = mylist[index_of_minimum]
    return minimum_item


# Use the new function
closest_to_1_1 = item_of_min_norm([1.0,1.0])
```

However, if I can guess your use case correctly, you probably want to use a **KDTree**.
See https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.html